# How to pass SIP over NAT64 (IPv6) for iOS app testing?

Tags: ios, sip, voip, appstore-approval

My App got rejected due to reason that app is not able to work with IPv6. While testing for both IPv4 and IPv6 network, app is working correctly.

My app is containing SIP traffic (VOIP app). But NAT64 is not able to pass SIP Traffic. So If app is tested by NAT64 network then how can I make my app approved on iOS platform?

Comment: what do you mean "NAT64 is not able to pass SIP Traffic"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  and/or the store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an architecture known as 464XLAT (RFC 6877) allows clients on IPv6-only networks to access IPv4-only Internet services, such as Skype. You need to use a SIIP converter on client side or on a middleware for IOS platfrom. Because iOS native CLAT (SIIP Translater) implementation does not exist. Instead, Apple requires all apps submitted to the App Store to work on IPv6 networks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But will SIP Traffic pass through NAT64 ? Can you please provide some more detail towards this? Exactly what can I do to make my app approved by Apple? Your help will be really very appreciated.